# How can I use snowflake jar in Bitnami Spark Docker container?

Tags: docker, scala, apache-spark, bitnami

I was able to create a Docker-based Bitnami standalone Spark instance and run Spark jobs on it. However, I'm not able not able to write data to Snowflake from the the Spark DataFrame.

I created a Dockerfile to copy the Snowflake jar to the image, but it still doesn't find the Snowflake plugin. However, if I check the jars folder, the jar file is in there. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 10) (172.19.0.3 executor 0): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.SnowflakeResultSetPartition
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/spark
USER root
COPY *.jar /opt/bitnami/spark/jars
```

What other settings should I be setting to get the Snowflake plugin to be recognized?

Here are my maven dependencies:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-spark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.837</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-snowflake_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0-spark_3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It may be worth spinning up the docker locally and running a job with the JVM option `-verbose:class`. It would display all the loaded JAR files and classe. Might give you a hint if your jar is being copied to the wrong place?

Comment: Which spark and spark-snowflake version are you using? As mentioned in their docs `The main version of spark-snowflake works with Spark 2.4. For use with Spark 2.3 and 2.2, please use tag vx.x.x-spark_2.3 and vx.x.x-spark_2.2.` Maybe you have a conflict of versions?

Comment: have you tried to package the connector code as part of your build file? please share the Maven/SBT build file that you are using for the code

Comment: @YayatiSule I added my dependencies to the posting above

Comment: What plugin are you using to build the JAR file? maven-assembly or maven-shade? I do not see a section for the <build>...</build> tag

Comment: you are using snowflake 2.12
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-snowflake_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0-spark_3.2</version>
    </dependency> 
and the spark docker latest. this can cause conflict

Answer (score 0):

It is a dependancy issue based on versions. You should use the spark docker related to the version you are referencing and not spark docker latest.